# Regex for checking a url format

Tags: regex, query-string

I need a regex for checking if a string starts with '/message/posts', next slash and some string is optional, but the next character should not be "?".

for example:

```
/message/posts => true
/message/posts?a=b => false
/message/posts/lalala => true
/message/posts/lalala?n=v => false
```

I tried next code, but I don't know what next:

```
^(\/message\/posts)(\/)?
```

Comment: `^\/message\/posts(?:\/\w+)*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:
`^\/message\/posts[^?]*$`

[RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY9sE5/2)

[^?] means "Match anything but ?", and * means "do this 0 or more times", until end of string anchor $.

You don't need to use capturing parentheses the way you have done, even if there is normally no harm caused by this. When you want to group stuff without capturing, try (?:stuff here) instead of (stuff here). See [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for info on this.